# fail for null arguments with @Inject

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jsr330

I've started using Spring 3 Java Config with the JSR-330 `@Inject` annotations. Unlike the Spring `@Autowire`, Spring does not fail at startup if the `@Inject` parameters are null. Is there a way to do this within Java Config?

**Edit:** Just a clarification, I would like this as the default behaviour so I don't have to put @Required on every field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `@Required` on a setter for the dependency, in addition to `@Inject`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'd like it as the default behaviour without having to put @Required on all the fields.